# Plotly "go.Parcoords" でレンジを動かした後の各変数の値を抽出したい

Tags: python, plotly-python

Plotlyの中に、各変数間の関係性をプロットできる機能があります。
https://plot.ly/python/parallel-coordinates-plot/

各変数のレンジはインタラクティブに手動で変更できます。
手動で変更した後の、min/maxの値を抽出したいのですが、その方法が分かりません。

どなたかご存知の方、ご教示いただけないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

Python版のPlotlyは、htmlベースのコードを作成する機能しか持っていません。グラフを表示するためには、Jupyter Notebook、Plotly社のアプリケーションサーバー等Webサーバーが必要になります。したがって、Python版のPlotly側で、インタラクティブな変更については情報を取得することは不可能です。

グラフのインタラクティブな情報を取得したいのであれば、plotly.jsを使う必要があります。簡単にできるかどうかはわかりませんが、plotly.jsはOSSでコードが公開されているので不可能ではないと思います。